# How to access log4net log file in Azure worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have setup log4net fileappender for my worker role as below using .NET 4.5 & VS2013.

```
<configSections>     <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net,  Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" /> </configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Then setting the log file path at run time using the below steps (briefly).

private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger       (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

Set the log file path - FileAppender.File = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LogFileStore").RootPath + "Log.txt"

Everything works fine and log file generated successfully and messages were written into it in worker role storage folder (LogFileStore - 10MB defined in .csdef).

But when I tried to attach the log file to a mail attachment in the code, it throws exception - "You can not access the file as it is being used by another process. How to fix it ?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Host = Host;
mail.Subject = "Error in the Data Load";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
var htmlBody = string.Empty;
htmlBody = "Error in Data Load and the Error is : </br></br>";
htmlBody += ErrorMessage;
mail.Body = htmlBody;
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LogFileStore").RootPath + "Log.txt"));
client.Send(mail);
```

Please help.
Thanks

Bhanu

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use File.Copy and create a copy of the log file. After sending the email, delete the temporary file that you created.

```
File.Copy(RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LogFileStore").RootPath + "Log.txt", RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("LogFileStore").RootPath + "LogTemp.txt", true);
```

Edit:

If File.Copy doesn't work, you can try one of two other options:

1 - In the "appender" section of the log4net configuration in the app.config, add

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

This has some performance overhead, as it will need to open and lock the file each time it writes instead of just holding the lock the entire time.

2 - Copy the file contents to a stream using FileShare.ReadWrite and attach the stream to the email or write to new file and attach

```
string logFileText using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    //read stream to file or directly to memory stream and attach
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Not at all. How does it allow to copy when it is being used by another process ?

Comment: @Bhanu Added two other methods to try

Comment: MinimalLock is already in place above. Got the same error when FileStream used. No luck.